# Hide/Disable WordPress Editor and Make Elementor Default Editor

Tags: wordpress, editor, elementor

I'm working with Elementor, I want to hide/disable the WordPress Editor option to edit any page/post instead I want to show only the Edit with Elementor option i.e I want to make Elementor my Default Editor.
In Image, You can see that there is an option "back to WordPress Editor" I want to show here only "Edit With Elementor" so that When I have selected a category and other stuff then I can edit it with Elementor.
How Can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Someone made a plugin for that here : **[Make Elementor your default editor](https://github.com/heyfletch/make-elementor-default-editor)**

**However**, if you need more control over the code, this is how it was made :

```php
<?php

/**
 * Make Elementor the default editor, not the WordPress Editor (Gutenberg or Classic)
 * Clicking the page title will take you to the Elementor editor directly
 * Even non-Elementor-edited pages will become Elementor-edited pages now
 * You can revert by clicking the "Back to WordPress Editor" button
 *
 * Author:  Joe Fletcher, https://fletcherdigital.com
 * URL:     https://gist.github.com/heyfletch/7c59d1c0c9c56cbad51ef80290d86df7
 * Credit:  mjakic https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178416/how-to-change-the-title-url-on-the-edit-post-screen
 * Credit:  Aurovrata Venet https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/
*/

/** Replace hyperlink in post titles on Page, Post, or Template lists with Elementor's editor link */
add_filter('get_edit_post_link', 'fd_make_elementor_default_edit_link', 10, 3 );
function fd_make_elementor_default_edit_link($link, $post_id, $context) {

    // Get current screen parameters
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    //check if $screen is object otherwise we may be on an admin page where get_current_screen isn't defined
    if( !is_object($screen) )
        return;

    // Post Types to Edit with Elementor
    $post_types_for_elementor = array(
        'page',
        'post',
        'elementor_library',
    );

    // When we are on a specified post type screen
    if ( in_array( $screen->post_type, $post_types_for_elementor ) && $context == 'display' ) {

        // Build the Elementor editor link
        $elementor_editor_link = admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $post_id . '&action=elementor' );

        return $elementor_editor_link;
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}

/** Add back the default Edit link action in Page and Post list rows */
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'fd_add_back_default_edit_link', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'fd_add_back_default_edit_link', 10, 2 );
function fd_add_back_default_edit_link( $actions, $post ) {

    // Build the Elementor edit URL
    $elementor_edit_url = admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $post->ID . '&action=edit' );

    // Rewrite the normal Edit link
    $actions['edit'] =
        sprintf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
            esc_url( $elementor_edit_url ),
            esc_html( __( 'Default WordPress Editor', 'elementor' ) )
        );

   return $actions;
}


/** (optional) Remove redundant "Edit with Elementor" link added by Elementor itself */
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'fd_remove_default_edit_with_elementor', 99, 2 );
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'fd_remove_default_edit_with_elementor', 99, 2 );
function fd_remove_default_edit_with_elementor( $actions, $post ) {

  // Rewrite the normal Edit link
  unset( $actions['edit_with_elementor'] );

  return $actions;
}

/** Alternative:  Rewrite just the Edit link, and leave the page title as original */
/** Rewrite the normal Edit link on lists of Pages and replace it with Elementor's edit link */
// add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'fd_elementor_modify_list_row_actions', 10, 2 );
// add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'fd_elementor_modify_list_row_actions', 10, 2 );
// function fd_elementor_modify_list_row_actions( $actions, $post ) {

//      // Build the Elementor edit URL
//      $elementor_edit_url = admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $post->ID . '&action=elementor' );

//      // Rewrite the normal Edit link
//      $actions['edit'] =
//        sprintf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
//         esc_url( $elementor_edit_url ),
//         esc_html( __( 'Elementor Editor', 'elementor' ) )
//          );

//     return $actions;
// }
```

Comment: I tried this, but this didn't work on the screen (shared a screen shot)